# Differential forms on the torus correspond to periodic forms on $\Bbb{R}^n$?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, differential-topology

Let $T^n=\Bbb{R^n/Z^n}$ be the torus. Is it possible say that forms on the torus bijectively correspond to forms on $\Bbb{R}^n$ invariant under translations by integers?

Comment: It would be technically incorrect, since forms on the torus are not forms on $\mathbb{R}^n$. But there's a natural bijection.

Comment: @DanielFischer I edited some words.

Comment: @Gobi, could you clarify in what capacity the "functions" appear in the forms on the torus? It is not clear what you are trying to transfer to Euclidean space exactly. Are you interested in writing an arbitrary form in terms of some basis forms using functional coefficients?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. The projection $\pi : \mathbf R^n\to T^n$ is a covering map. A necessary and sufficient condition for a differential form on $\mathbf R^n$ to descend to $T^n$ is that it be constant on the fibres of $\pi$.

(Of course, for a general map it doesn't make sense to say that a differential form is constant on the fibres, but for a Galois covering, the tangent spaces at two different points in a given fibre can be identified using the covering group.)